# What happens when you promote a widget in QtCreator?

Tags: qt, inheritance

Lets say I have everything that is needed to promote a widget (I will use a `QLineEdit` in this example) to a class called `MyClass`. `MyClass` inherits from `QWidget` and defines its own functions.

When I promote the `QLineEdit` to an instance of `MyClass`, what happens behind the scenes? I know that the `QLineEdit` is a child of `QWidget`, so `MyClass` and `QLineEdit` are related in that factor. But what happens to the properties? Does the `QLineEdit` still retain the properties specific to a `QLineEdit`? How does it just change "types"?

Other than the fact that `QLineEdit` still retains the properties of `QWidget` (`MyClass` inherits from the class), I am unsure what happens behind this promotion of widgets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you promote from QLineEdit to MyClass instead if having :

`QLineEdit *lineedit=new QLineEdit(centralWidget);`

You will have:

`MyClass * lineedit=new MyClass(centralWidget);`

And you can call your functions from MyClass in a normal way, you can open the ui.h file and see for yourself.

Comment: Interesting. Will `MyClass` have to have a constructor for a QLineEdit?

Comment: Thanks, makes sense now. Just wondering, if I created a QPushButton, set the text of the button to "Press me", and promoted it to a `MyClass`, then it gives me an error for trying to use `setText()` on a `MyClass` object. Does this mean I cannot "customize" my widget and then promote the widget to my custom class?

Comment: The only way you could call setText() was if MyClass was inherited from QPushButton() (QAbstractButton) or you implemented your own setText function in MyClass.

Comment: is there a way for promoting a QLabel to MyLabel and automatically create the class MyLabel that inherits from QLabel?

Answer (score 2):

Since `MyClass` extends `QLineEdit` in a public way, it inherits all properties and is able to fully replace `QLineEdit`. Qt Creator just changes the implementation. That's exactly what polymorpism "is made for". Qt Creator knows nothing about your additional methods and doesn't need to, it treats `MyClass` as a `QLineEdit`. That works because `MyClass` **is-a** `QLineEdit`.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I still have some questions.. so the only change it makes is that MyClass inherits QLineEdit? Also, when I promote the widget to `MyClass`, the file that creates the widget does something like this? `QLineEdit lineEdit = new MyClass(ui->widget)`? Does that mean that future objects of MyClass will have QLineEdit members?